# how to traverse array in this format?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, data-structures

There is a array [a,b,c,d,e,f] and I want to traverse and print in form of a,f,b,e,c,d. That is one element from start and another from end. Here is what I have tried.

```
int start=0;
int end=arr.length-1;
while(start!=end)
{
    System.out.print(arr[start]+" "+arr[end]);
    start++;
    end--;
}
```

But this is giving error and that is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: at the moment start will never == end as they will 'pass' each other without meeting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `start!=end` then for even number of values in array the indexes will never be same, instead try this

```
    int start = 0;
    char[] arr = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
    int end = arr.length - 1;
    while (start <= end) {
        if (start == end) {
            System.out.print(arr[start]);
        } else {
            System.out.print(arr[start] + " " + arr[end] + " ");
        }
        start++;
        end--;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please change condition to `start < end`. If not, in your example, start = 2, and end = 3, the next loop will be start = 3 and end = 2. Eventually, `start` will keep increasing and more than array length.

You also need to print the middle element outside the loop in case array length is odd as well.

Comment: If the lengthof the array is odd you will skip the middle element

Answer (score 0):

Change the while condition to `start <= end`

Answer (score 0):

There will be no such a condition like  start == end

Your variables will act like below

*Start = 0 , 1, 2, 3

*End = 5, 4, 3, 2

You need to think about how to break your while loop

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to use a for loop, as in this example:

```
public void printTraverseArray(String[] array) {
    int rounds = array.length/2;
    for(int i = 0; i < rounds; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i] + " " + array[array.length - 1 - i] + " ");
    }
    if(array.length % 2 != 0) { //odd number of items in array
        System.out.print(array[rounds]);
    }
}
```

As you see here, we also take in account the situation where there are an odd number of items in your array. The rounds variable will contain the number of times we need to print something (for odd numbers the rounds-1, because 5/2 = 2.5 = 2 in integers). This works nice for even numbers, because we walk from the beginning and the end at the same time.
For odd numbers, we come one round short, but this is a special round, as we only need to print one item. When you calculate the position of this item, it is exactly the same as the rounds variable.
This is a more complicated algorithm than the other answers, but I think it is worth your time to look at it.
When anyone has questions, I will be glad to answer them.